# How to detach PIN tool from a process

Tags: memory, instrumentation

I was wondering if anybody has experience with PIN tool (from http://www.pintool.org/). 
I can attach the pin tool to an process by its pid by calling

```
./pin -pid MY_PID -t MY_PIN_TOOL.so
```

But, how can I detach the pin tool from the process while the process resumes running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin can relinquish control of application any time when invoked via PIN_Detach. Control is returned to the original uninstrumented code and the application runs at native speed. Thereafter no instrumented code is ever executed.

The example can be found in source/tools/ManualExamples/detach.cpp. [Link](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97998/Pin/html/index.html#DetachPin) to article

Comment: @vo01d: Thanks for your reply. I have read the article before, but I don't know how to invoke PIN_Detach. I tried to call ./pin -pid PID -t /PATH/detach.so, but it did not work. Can you elaborate more about how to call it? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to call ./pin -pid PID -t /PATH/detach.so, and I also tried ./pin -pid PID -detach_reattach, but it did not work with pid. Can you elaborate more about how to call it? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should just add the call to PIN_Detach() in MY_PIN_TOOL.so just add some logic on when you want to detach.

Comment: jess, remember to accept answers (press the tick) to thank posters.